# How do I get crash logs and stack traces from WinRT apps written in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, crash-reports

I have just started working on a Windows Store App written in C#, it has not yet been published to the Windows Store. When I give a debug build of the app being developed to my testing team and it crashes where can they find the crash log and stack trace? Do I need to do anything when building my application? I'm looking for the standard solution, **not** a third party library or something that sends me reports from end-users. I'm coming from an Android world where the ADB logcat always contains the Java stack trace, I'm looking for the equivalent in C#/WinRt.

Comment: There a standard one.  You need to handle the entire process of creating the log file yourself.  **This is true of ANY .NET application**  You can get the mini dump file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730250/how-to-debug-a-windows-store-app-that-crashes-on-a-customers-machine?rq=1 or use quality reports: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/06/27/improving-apps-with-quality-reports.aspx

Comment: My app is not published in the store yet, I am in development now, I don't have access to any Windows Store Dashboard.

Comment: The most probable method is using the EventViewer in Windows (View Event Logs). There nearly all application crashes are reported. For .NET applications (including ModernUI) a quite good error description is logged AFAIK.

Comment: I looked in the event viewer and I see the crash, but I don't see the C# stack trace.

Comment: This page from the documentation is looking helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception.aspx It looks like I must register an event handler here and write the stack trace to a log file myself? The scary part is it says " However, the type, message, and stack trace of this exception object are not guaranteed to match those of the original exception that was raised".

Comment: @satur9nine - If you want the stacktrack you have to write your own log file with that information.

Answer (score 0):

Crash dumps will contain the callstack and much more.

To collect crash dumps, first, execute the following regedit script:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps]
"DumpFolder"="C:\\Temp\\CrashDumps"
"DumpCount"=dword:00000002
"DumpType"=dword:00000002
```

Second, reproduce the crash.

Third, stop crash dump recollection by executing:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps]
"DumpFolder"=-
"DumpCount"=-
"DumpType"=-
```

Fourth, get the crash dump from **C:\Temp\CrashDumps**

[More info at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).